# Find non-existent relations

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have three kind of nodes (a), (b) and (c). (a) and (b) are always connected by a relation (a)--(b).

I was looking to find all nodes type (a) that

a) have not a relation to (c)

b) fulfill a condition on a property of (b)

I tried several approaches e.g. like

```
MATCH (a), (c) WHERE NOT (a)--(c) MATCH (a)--(b) WHERE b.condition = "foo" return a
```

or

```
MATCH (a)--(b)
WHERE b.condition = "foo" AND NOT EXISTS ((a)--(c))
RETURN a
```

but I also got nodes (a) that have a connection to (b) and (c). Seems I missed something - any hint is very appreciated, thanks.

Comment: You do not seem to specify any labels. Do you have separate labels for `a`, `b` and `c`? Also, a minor comment: instead of `NOT EXISTS ((a)--(c))`, you can simply use `NOT (a)--(c)`, if variable `c` was previously introduced.

Comment: I second what Gabor says. If (a), (b) and (c) are properly defined your query is correct. But otherwise you're doing a cartesian product of three full node scans and basically anything will go ...

Comment: Your second query seems to be correct. Maybe you should add a sample data set and the expected result in the question.

Comment: Thanks for all your input, I always use labels but didnt show them here as I thought this would simplify the query - me bad :) So your comments are very appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the following...

1) Nodes aren't labeled (bad for performance)

2) (a) will have 1 and only 1 relation to (b)

You can tell if (a) has a (c) relation by counting it's edges

```
MATCH (a)--(b{condition:"foo"})
WITH a, COUNT((a)--()) as count
WHERE count = 1
RETURN a
```

Note that this is not performent though. If you can, you should specify the labels and relationship direction. Also, check properties in MATCH instead of WHERE when you can as that is usually faster.

Here is the same query with proper labels in place.

```
MATCH (a:A)-->(b:B{condition:"foo"})
WHERE NOT (a)--(:C)
RETURN a
```

As for what is wrong with this query

```
MATCH (a), (c) WHERE NOT (a)--(c) MATCH (a)--(b) WHERE b.condition = "foo" return a
```

You are matching every node against every other node, checking if there exists a node that (a) is not related to, and then matching all (a) where `(a)--(b{condition:"foo"})`. In short, the way you match `NOT (a)--(c)` is very expensive, and does nothing because it is not the filter you meant.

The second query is closer, but doesn't compile because (c) was not defined. It also is still the wrong filter (this time asking if (a) is related to no one). Here is the second query fixed. (`<>` is the "not equal" operator in Cypher)

```
MATCH (a)--(b), (c)
WHERE b.condition = "foo" AND (b) <> (c) AND NOT (a)--(c)
RETURN a
```

Note that without labels, this query is still wrong, and is just very expensive edge counting. You need a label or property to identify if a node is an a, b, or c to get the correct results.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this very helpful analysis and all the effort you did to explain - very well done. I am happy you nudged me into the right direction, the query now works as expected using labels as well. Happy to have people like you who put effort in teaching others!